# GNU readline and key bindings

Tags: gnu, readline, key-bindings

I've read from the GNU getline documentation that it's capable for binding some callback functions to some keys. I know already how to bind an action to the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key using `rl_bind_key` function.

But how can I use it to bind some action to the following keys?:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>PAUSE</kbd>/<kbd>BREAK</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>

int my_cool_readline_func (int count, int key) {
   printf ("key pressed: %d\n", key);
   rl_on_new_line ();
   return 0;
}

int main(void) {
     rl_command_func_t my_cool_readline_func;
     rl_bind_key ('\t', my_cool_readline_func);
     rl_bind_key (27, my_cool_readline_func); /* ascii code for ESC */
     rl_bind_keyseq ("\\C-a", my_cool_readline_func);

     while (1) {
         char *line = readline ("rl> ");
     }
}
```

If your are running a GNU system (or one of its variants) then run:

```
info readline "command line editing" "introduction" # notation convention
info readline "programming" "readline" "biding" # biding functions
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expect. No matter whether I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+TAB</kbd> (or any other combination with <kbd>TAB</kbd>), it shows the output from the hook function "key pressed: 9". There's also something strange about the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key: I need to press it twice, because the first press doesn't make anything visible. <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> doesn't display anything. And function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F12</kbd> give the same key code as <kbd>Esc</kbd> (255), but additionaly inserts some gibberish in the command line. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: I'm not having the same problems, did you find a solution SasQ?