# custom readline functions in bash commandline?

Tags: c, bash, readline

Code from [GNU readline and key bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257737/gnu-readline-and-key-bindings) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>

int my_cool_readline_func (int count, int key) {
   printf ("key pressed: %d\n", key);
   rl_on_new_line ();
   return 0;
}

int main(void) {
     rl_command_func_t my_cool_readline_func;
     rl_bind_key ('\t', my_cool_readline_func);
     rl_bind_key (27, my_cool_readline_func); /* ascii code for ESC */
     rl_bind_keyseq ("\\C-a", my_cool_readline_func);

     while (1) {
         char *line = readline ("rl> ");
     }
}
```

Is it possible to use this kind of custom readline functions in bash commandline?

For example, I have tried these (a custom function can be much more complex, of course):

```
bind '"\C-t" beginning-of-line shell-kill-word'

bind '"\C-t" beginning-of-line, shell-kill-word'

bind '"\C-t" beginning-of-line; shell-kill-word'
```

None of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this binding is the key to understanding how this is done:

```
 "\C-x\"": "\"\"\C-b"
```

Read "When I press Ctrl+X and then `"`, insert two quotes (`\"\"`) and move the cursor once to the left (`\C-b`) so it ends up between the two double quotes.

On the right hand side of the `:`, you can only have a single readline function or a "macro" or a single shell function. A macro is a sequence of keystrokes.

So what you need to do is assign the functions you want to keys and then use the **keys** in the macro:

```
 bind '"\C-t":"\C-a\ed"'
```

See also: [Complex keybinding in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366450/complex-keybinding-in-bash)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. How do I make it so when I hit tab, my custom function is called?

Comment: @GregSchmit The question is a bit confusing. I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: `rl_bind_key` was actually not working for me and I thought the OP was having the same problem. In my case it turned out that it was because I accidentally was using libedit rather than GNU Readline. I ended up figuring it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588197/why-does-rl-bind-key-with-custom-function-fail-in-readline-on-osx-macos/47588198#47588198