# Readline & NCurses, handle special keys and keys combinations

Tags: c, readline, ncurses, keypad, libreadline

I'm replicating an [Irssi interface](https://irssi-import.github.io/themes/) for a student project. I would like to use [NCurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) for the text interface, and [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to provide better text-editing capabilities while writing messages.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691652/using-gnu-readline-how-can-i-add-ncurses-in-the-same-program), [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709979/3566655) and [project](https://github.com/ulfalizer/readline-and-ncurses) provided me with a great starting point.

My problem is that I would like to have an input/event loop like this:

```
int ch;
while (exit_condition) {
    ch = wgetch(window);
    switch (ch) {
    case ERR: continue;
    case KEY_F(1): /* do something */ break;
    case KEY_UP: /* do something else */ break;
    default: forward_to_readline(ch); break;
    }
}
```

But in order to match `KEY_F(n)` or `KEY_UP` I need to enable `keypad(window, TRUE)`, which will modify the input and make it unusable for readline.

From the manual:

> If keypad is TRUE, and a function key is pressed, the  token  for  that
>   function key is returned instead of the raw characters.
>
> When a character that could be the beginning of a function key  is 
>   received (which, on modern terminals, means an escape character),
>   curses sets a timer. If the remainder of the sequence does not come in 
>   within the designated time,  the character is passed through; 
>   otherwise, the function key value is returned. For this reason, many 
>   terminals experience a delay between the time a user presses the
>   escape key and the escape is returned to the program.

Here are my thoughts:

- Is there a function to reverse the effect of `keypad` ?
- Should I implement myself the behaviour of `keypad` ? I suppose I must also do this if I want to catch events like Shift + Up. I'd be glad to have examples of this.
- Can readline give me the combination of keys if I can't obtain it form NCurses ? maybe with key binding callbacs ([relevant ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257737/gnu-readline-and-key-bindings)) ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's multiple questions.  Briefly:

- the reverse of the `keypad` function is by calling that for a given window with the parameter set to **`FALSE`**.
- some applications implement their own version of `keypad`/`wgetch`, but (given that you can control the timeout with ncurses' `ESCDELAY`), there's not a lot of gain there unless you wanted to be portable, say, to Solaris curses.
- you wouldn't get any improvement with *shift + up*, for instance (that's a terminal-dependent escape sequence)
- readline doesn't look at the capabilities in the terminal database which list *shift + up* (it's not in the subset of termcap which it knows about). What it could do for you is associate a string with a readline function.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll guess there could not be a better person to answer my questions. I'll go with the readline function.
What I meant by reverse `keypad` is that given a token for a function key, I could retreive the sequence of escape codes at the origin of the token.